# How to install VOCE for C++?

Tags: java, c++, qt, text-to-speech, voice-recognition

I am trying to install the VOCE api, which is a voice recognition API built for both C++ and Java. This is the second time I am working with external C++ libs, and first time working with Java + C++ api.

Voce link - http://voce.sourceforge.net/

In this API there is really no .lib files, but only .jar files! I read the whole "read me" file but no good clue at how to set this up for C++. I am using QT, the latest version which works with Visual Studio 2010 compiler.

How can I set this up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the C++ header and examples from VOCE, it seems that the C++ option is using the [Java Native Interface (JNI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) to allow a C++ program to run an embedded JVM. All of the code is still in Java, but you just need to `#'include` he `voce.h` in your project and make sure you have set up JNI correctly.

There is a [useful JNI tutorial here](http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html).

Comment: Correct. The readme (from voce.sourceforge.net) says - "Library build instructions ...C++ - Same as Java instructions.  The Voce Java jar is used by the C++ version via the Java Native Interface." And "Using Voce in your application - 
See the 'synthesisTest' and 'recognitionTest' sample applications for examples."

Comment: I still don't understand how. I executed all the .bat files they have provided, but what really has happened?

Comment: As i remember, all you need is to 1) place the required lib in correct place, 2)include voce.h in your project, 3)set paths to incliudes and libraries correctly in the project, 4)compile and build.

Answer (score 2):

For C++ it's better to just use CMUSphinx project pocketsphinx:

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net

It provides comparable interface in C++ and Voce is using it anyway.

Comment: Yes, I understand. Anyway, I decided to move with Microsoft SAPI 5.3