# C++ Speech recognition API

Tags: c++, artificial-intelligence, speech-recognition, voice, voice-recognition

I am seeking for a C++ speech recognition/voice recognition API. I have gone through few, including VOCE and pocketphenix. However this is my requirement

1. Text to speech
2. Speech to text (voice commands - I am planning to convert voice into string and check whether it is a command)
3. Identify my voice (not mandatory)

VOCE api seems not to provide what I am asking for, and pocketphenix seems extremely complex. The API will be used with QT - latest version which works with Visual Studio 2010 compiler.

I have heard there is a API provided by Microsoft, but I am willing to stay away from Microsoft APIs as much as possible.

I am using MS Windows 7 ultimate, so the it is enough if the API works with windows.

The API should be free and better if opensource because I will be using this in my Final Year project at university.

Comment: In what way does Voce not provide what you're looking for?

Comment: @JBentley: Voice to text. Apart from that, I really don't understand how to use it with C++. I know JNI is used, but every article says how you can use C++ with Java, not Java with C++ :( - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16261390/how-to-install-voce-for-c/16262602?noredirect=1#16262602

Comment: @JBentley: Please provide your comment as an answer. I will mark it as solved :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [Voce home page](http://voce.sourceforge.net/), it does text to voice and voice to text. As for using it with C++, when I look at the source code, I can see a C++ header [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/voce/code/HEAD/tree/src/c++/), and there are some instructions [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/voce/code/HEAD/tree/readme.txt). I can't advise you specifically on JNI as I have no experience with it.

Comment: The code in this link is very old and doesn't work. Libraries aren't updated.