# Voce c++ include setup

Tags: c++, visual-studio, speech-recognition, voce

I have seen many posts about that, but I just don't understand everything.

Could someone write ALL include and library directories and linkers I need to add to run Voce with c++

I've tried:

Include Dir: 
\voce-0.9.1\src\c++
\voce-0.9.1\lib
\ProgramFiles\java\jdk1.8.0_101\include
\ProgramFiles\java\jdk1.8.0_101\include\win32
\ProgramFiles\java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin
\ProgramFiles\java\jdk1.8.0_101\lib

Library Dir:
\ProgramFiles\java\jdk1.8.0_101\lib
\ProgramFiles\java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin

Linker input:
Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\lib

Comment: Why do you even try to understand it? Send me your project details. I will do it for you free.

Comment: Did you try to implement the example linked from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16261390/how-to-install-voce-for-c)? Post what you have tried so far...

Comment: I need just a simple CLR Console Application that can recognize just few words

Comment: update with what i have tried. Im geting error "library machine type x64 conflicts with target machine type x86 "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use Voce, it was craziest idea to wrap java library with C++ code.

There are many C++ speech APIs, commercial and open source. You can use Microsoft's speech API, you can use Pocketsphinx, you can use Kaldi. There are many alternatives.

Comment: Do you know where I can find example code for Pocketsphinx in c++ ?