# I'm trying to use voce to create a voice recognition program and im having trouble with the include statements?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, voice-recognition, voce

this is in the voce.h file which i included in my header files tab

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
```

this is in my .cpp file

```
#include <voce/voce.h>

#ifdef WIN32
#include <windows.h>  
#else
#include <unistd.h>
#endif
```

in both files it says cannot open source file jni.h and voce.h respectively. I went to project properties and included 
"C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0/include/";"C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0/include/win32"
into the additional include libraries tab. Any help?
P.S I might be way out of my depth here...

Comment: any specific reason that u have included C#??

Comment: I was trying to figure out microsoft speech recognition earlier and got the c# there mixed with the c++ here any way to change that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Voce c++ include setup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40139990/voce-c-include-setup)